# Хранение игровой карты

Tags: python, разработка-игр

Решил я сделать бегалку в компилере питона с реализацией координат, пока ничего лучше вложенных списков не придумал.

В списках будет что-то вроде такого `coordinates = [[Spawn],[Дерево, , Дерево],[Река, река, река, дерево],[],[],[]]`

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы например когда игрок находится в области от 0, 0 до 10, 10 при введении команды ему выводилось образно 'Ты сейчас в лесу'

Пока не представляю как это так реализовать.

Может быть для этого надо использовать какой-нибудь отдельный модуль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: изначально карту заполняем строкой, в ней условно разными символами обозначаем разные объекты. Например, пусть точка - это пустое место (можно пробел, но пробелы сложнее считать), `!` - дерево, `#` - река. Потом разбиваем текст на отдельные строки, получаем список.

```
game_map = """
...#......
...#......
...##.....
....##....
.....#####
..........
..!!!.....
!!!!!.....
!!!!!.....
!!!!!!....
""".strip().splitlines()
```

Проверка:

```
coords = (0, 0)

current_area = game_map[coords[0]][coords[1]]
if current_area == ".":
    print("Вы в поле")
elif current_area == "!":
    print("Вы в лесу")
elif current_area == "#":
    print("Вы возле реки")
```

Если нужна какая-то более сложная логика, и объекты карты должны быть настоящими объектами, а не просто символами, то саму карту (например, в файле) можно хранить точно так же, но при старте превращать каждый символ в настоящий объект, проверять текущую местность уже проверять через `isinstance`:

```
game_map = """
...#......
...#......
...##.....
....##....
.....#####
..........
..!!!.....
!!!!!.....
!!!!!.....
!!!!!!....
""".strip().splitlines()


class Field:
    ...


class River:
    ...


class Forest:
    ...


def convert(c):
    if c == ".":
        return Field()
    elif c == "#":
        return River()
    elif c == "!":
        return Forest()


object_map = [
    [convert(item) for item in row]
    for row in game_map
]


coords = (0, 0)
current_area = object_map[coords[0]][coords[1]]
if isinstance(current_area, Field):
    print("Вы в поле")
elif isinstance(current_area, Forest):
    print("Вы в лесу")
elif isinstance(current_area, River):
    print("Вы возле реки")
```

---

По поводу отдельного модуля для хранения карты: если у вас карта не гигантская (не 10 на 10, а допустим 100к на 100к), то не вижу особого смысла заморачиваться, достаточно просто списка.

Если гигантская - то возможно придется уплотняться, например хранить каждую ячейку карты в одном байте.

Если гигантская еще и пустая в основном - можно использовать какие-нибудь изощренные структуры данных, типа деревьев квадрантов (quadtree см. [Дерево квадрантов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)), чтобы не хранить пустоту, а хранить только те куски карты, где что-то есть. Например такое имеет смысл для [игры "Жизнь"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%C2%BB) на очень больших полях, чтобы не обсчитывать пустые пространства.